# Spring App design for request scope

Tags: java, spring, oop

I am having an issue with the application design/arch any one can please suggest an better approach

I have lets say two Manager Object

Example

- Asia Manager
- Europe Manager

these two manager objects perform same operations on diffrent country objects
Example

```
@Service
Male_Manager
{
   @Autowired
   India_Male_operation

   @Autowired
   Pakistan_Male_operation

   @Autowired
   China_Male_operation
   // and many more
}
```

similarly for

```
@Service
Female_Manager
{
   @Autowired
   India_FeMale_operation

   @Autowired
   Pakistan_FeMale_operation

   @Autowired
   China_FeMale_operation
   // and many more
}
```

After that i have one request processor object

Request_processor which will analyze the type of request

```
@Service
RequestProcessor{

@Autowired
Male_manager

@Autowired
FeMale_manager

public void processRequest(Req r){

   if (r == male )
   {
          // call the male manager and check the location and process
          // example code
          Male_Manager.getIndianManager().processRequest
   } 
   else 
   {

   }
}
```

In my case all the objects are at request scope

when request processor object is created all the objects also created and set, but its an high level decision to make all the objects at request scope

every time creation of objects for every request i do not think its a good design

since when the request is of type male and belongs to india
only Male_Manager and India_male_manager are required

since all those are auto-wired unnecessary objects get created

and i using spring 3.2, and i cannot use @Lazy annotation which is available in Spring4.0

can any one show the better solution for these kind of problem

Comment: Use ApplicationContext.getBean instead of autowired...?

Comment: earlier i used to use it, but my bad boss is against it, strict instructions to not use the getBean

Comment: You have a social problem, not a technology problem :)

Comment: may be, any possible solution plz